# Getting Run-time error in c++ for calculating LCM of two Number

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have make my program to calculate LCM of two number..It has no syntax error
but after entering number it has stopped working.. Please help to remove this Error .. Very Very Thanks for help in Advance....

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter Your Two Number : ";
 int num1, num2, big, i, lcm = 1;
 cin >> num1 >> num2;
 big = num1;
 if(num2 > big)
 big = num2;
 for(i = 1; i <= big/2; ++i)
 {
  if(num1 % i == 0)
    if(num2 % i == 0)
      lcm *= i;
 }
 cout << "LCM of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is " << lcm;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running in a debugger, it will stop when a crash happens, and then you can examine the call stack and walk up it if the debugger doesn't stop in your code. You can also examine the values of variables to see that they are okay.

Comment: Also, does it "stop working" for *all* inputs, or just some special inputs? If only for some input, please give us some example of input that *works* and some that *don't* work.

Comment: What do you mean with *"stopped working"*? Does it produce wrong results? That's because your logic is incorrect. Or does it not terminate normally? If so, give us the inputs to reproduce that.

Comment: When i enter two number in console..like 6 and 10 ..after that it shows the message "stopped working" and doesn't give any output in my console

Comment: Huh, does not happen with gcc, but the error message sounds like Windows. OP: What compiler are you using? And can anyone reproduce this? I see no reason for this code not to run (although, as I said, the result will be nonsense).

Comment: Your code, as shown in the question, [works very well for e.g. `6` and `10` as input](http://ideone.com/LerxeK). You must do something else that you do not show us. Did you copy and paste the actual code, or rewritten it when you wrote the question? Do you actual code start the loop with a zero?

Comment: I am using Code::Block gcc compiler

Comment: Oh! Sorry my Actual code Loop started with 0...But why is not showing correct Output...

Comment: So please [edit] your question to actually reproduce the question to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is output you get and what is output you expect?

Answer (score -1):

If the loop starts with zero (as you say it does in a comment), then you will have e.g. `num1 % 0` which is division by zero, something which is not mathematically possible and will cause a crash in your program.